# How to get the public IP address of a client in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using `httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()`, but when this program published to linux and used nginx as well (listens port 80 and proxy pass to localhost:5000), it always get **127.0.0.1** (my request is not from the server, so it should not be 127.0.0.1) .

Comment: Sounds like you're getting the proxy server ip. Depending on the proxy you might have a header like X-forwarded-for with the client ip